# Custom exception in Ruby 2.3 and 2.4

Tags: ruby, exception, ruby-2.3, ruby-2.4

I would like to rescue some code with a custom class in Ruby 2.3 and 2.4.
But unlike with the previous versions (such as 2.2 which was working great), I have some troubles. Here an example:

Given this class:

```
class CustomError < StandardError
end
```

This code is successfully rescued:

```
begin
  'foo'.bar(:boom)
rescue
  puts 'THIS IS FINE.'
end

# => printing "THIS IS FINE." on the screen
```

This one is also successfully rescued:

```
begin
  'foo'.bar(:boom)
rescue StandardError
  puts 'THIS IS FINE.'
end

# => printing "THIS IS FINE." on the screen
```

But not this one:

```
begin
  'foo'.bar(:boom)
rescue CustomError
  puts 'THIS IS FINE.'
end
```

This message is raised:

> undefined method `bar' for "foo":String (NoMethodError)

I don't know why my custom exception class is not handled.

Comment: Take a look at the message: a `NoMethodError` was raised, not a `CustomError`.

Comment: BTW, this is _not_ specific to Ruby 2.3 or 2.4.

Comment: It is not specific to 2.3 or 2.4, but it worked with previous versions of Ruby such as 2.1 and 2.2.
`NoMethodError` inherits from `StandardError`. And therefore considering Ruby's Exception Hierarchy, it should be rescuable with my `CustomError` class.

Comment: Your conclusion is wrong. Both, `Float` and `Integer` inherit from `Numeric`, but neither `1.is_a?(Float)`, nor `0.5.is_a?(Integer)` is `true`. Same with the exceptions. Just because both inherit from `StandardError` doesn't mean that you can rescue a `NoMethodError` with your `CustomError` (or an `ArgumentError` with an `IndexError`). A `rescue CustomError` will rescue `CustomError` and its subclasses. It won't rescue its ancestors or siblings.

Comment: Do you think there is no way to rescue this `NoMethodError` exception using a custom class?

Comment: I'm surprised because it worked before.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? (and no, it really doesn't work that way in Ruby 2.2 or any other Ruby version)

Answer (score 1):

You rescue `CustomError`, but `NoMethodError` is being raised. `NoMethodError` inherits `StandardError`, that's why it can be rescued with `rescue StandardError`.